# CSS selecting a number input

Tags: css

Really basic question but please read to the bottom for the things I have tried.  I have the following for an input box:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="vendor.day_of_the_month" name="" class="text-radio" max="31" min="1">
```

And the following CSS:

```
input[type=number] .text-radio{
  vertical-align: middle; 
  margin: 0px; 
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #909090;
  box-shadow:none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

For some reason the code around the borders do not seem to work. What seems odd is:

1. When I change the width of the input box in the CSS that seems to effect a change which seems to indicate it is NOT a selectivity issue
2. When I remove the "number" type from the HTML the formatting works which would seem to indicate the CSS code works.

Is there something special around how you have to format borders for a number input I am missing?

Comment: Try to put '!important;' like border-bottom: 1px solid #909090 !important;

Comment: FYI, `-ms-border-radius` and `-o-border-radius` don't exist. You don't need any of the prefixes for `border-radius` anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it is the space in your css between `input[type=number]` and `.text-radio{`

```
input[type=number].text-radio{
  vertical-align: middle; 
  margin: 0px; 
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #909090;
  box-shadow:none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/y33zR/)

Answer (score 1):

I think error is in your selector you are using it wrong 
use just

```
.text-radio
```

or

```
input[type=number]
```

or if you want to use both then try this

```
input[type=number].text-radio
```

mean remove space b/w slectors because  space is used when we want to add css to a child of a selector.